# How do I know if Doxygen is Locked

Tags: doxygen

How do I know if Doxygen is locked or just taking a long time to finish because it is a big project.

There are 1500 .md files with simple markdown (mostly tables).  There are no source files.

Here is what I can see after running for 45 minutes:

[image]

[image]

[EDIT] It finished in about 1.25 hours.  Still would like to know how to monitor its progress.

[EDIT] Per @Marged's linked page below I will try to run `doxygen` with the undocumented `-b` option that will tell `doxygen` not to buffer the messages it sends to the screen.  Presumably this will give me better more periodic updates what it is up to.  Next time I run `doxygen` I will report back what I find.  Perhaps as an answer.

Comment: Can you see progress in the  log / stdout when running doxygen verbosely ? Like in http://doxygen.10944.n7.nabble.com/Verbosity-level-td1076.html